# Any advantages to using Linq to SQL over Entity Framework 4 for new SQL Server only simple projects?

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am planning to work on a new ASP.NET WebForms site in .NET 4.0. I used to use Linq to SQL and now I am thinking about EF4. My database is SQL Server only ever, simple business objects and most probably one to one relationships between Business objects and database tables.

It seems EF4 in its simplistic form works very much like Linq to SQL as an ORM. Drag the tables into the designer and with LINQ to do the database stuff.

Instead of learning and using two ORM's, it seems EF4 can do all of it. From the simple to the complex projects. From SQL Server only to hybrid database engines.

Will I miss anything if I go with EF4 only all the way for all kinds of projects and leave LINQ to SQL behind? I know EF4 is more complex (steeper learning curve) for simple projects but I don't find this a good reason to split my energy & time between two ORM's when one (EF4) can do it all.

Comment: EF4 is a much better investment of your personal time than L2S.  It's relatively subjective though depending on your project requirements now and in the future.

Answer (score -1):

I think the main negative point about EF4 apart from the steeper learning curve is its performance. Linq to Sql is faster and if that is important for your project than you might have to consider choosing Linq to Sql or straight ADO.NET instead.

However in most cases when performance is not a crucial issue for either simple or more complex projects I share your idea of not splitting the efforts and concentrating only on EF4.

Comment: Can you back up the claim that EF is slower than Linq to Sql?